# SailsJS Model checking for uniqueness in type:array

Tags: sails.js

I have a model User and I have an

```
attribute: {
 lived:{
  type: 'array',
  defaultsTo: []
 } 
}
```

Now I need to check for uniqueness within the array. Suppose that I cannot have ['New York', 'New York'], is there a model validation? Or should I have a before create/update validation?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do it in a life cycle call back. I would recommend beforeValidate or afterValidate so it runs on both create/update.

Note, lodash is a dependency in sails, so I would use that to check for your duplicates in the array.